# conversion date time

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting minutes from this query

```
(SELECT (X_GSA_LEAVE_SITE - X_GSA_ARRIVE_ONSITE) * 24 * 60 AS difference_in_minutes 
FROM table_x_gsa_time_stamps 
WHERE X_TIME_STAMPS2X_DISPTCHFE = dfe.objid and rownum=1) Adj_Handle_time,
```

I need hh:mm format.. how can i achieve this

Comment: What about calculating the number of hours into an integer by dividing the result of your query by 60, and then using modulus function (i.e. `x % 60`) to get the minutes? If you need it as text, simply cast the results and concatenate Hours + ':' + minutes.

Comment: What do you expect when the interval is longer than 24 hours?

Comment: How do you represent a result like 33.85 minutes (if you do the math, that means 33 minutes and 51 seconds) in the `hh:mi` format? (Be careful with the format model elements: you wrote `mm` but that means months, not minutes; minutes is `mi`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TRUNC(((X_GSA_LEAVE_SITE - X_GSA_ARRIVE_ONSITE) * 24 * 60)/60) || ':' ||
     (((X_GSA_LEAVE_SITE - X_GSA_ARRIVE_ONSITE) * 24 * 60) 
                - TRUNC(((X_GSA_LEAVE_SITE - X_GSA_ARRIVE_ONSITE) * 24 * 60)/60)*60) 
FROM table_x_gsa_time_stamps 
WHERE X_TIME_STAMPS2X_DISPTCHFE = dfe.objid 
and rownum=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly simplified version:

```
select x_gsa_arrive_onsite
     , x_gsa_leave_site
     , trunc((x_gsa_leave_site - x_gsa_arrive_onsite) * 24) ||':'||
       trunc(mod((x_gsa_leave_site - x_gsa_arrive_onsite) * 24 * 60, 60)) as onsite_hhmi
from   table_x_gsa_time_stamps ts;
```

gives

```
X_GSA_ARRIVE_ONSITE X_GSA_LEAVE_SITE   ONSITE_HHMI
------------------- ------------------ -----------
01-SEP-2018         01-SEP-2018 12:34  12:34
01-SEP-2018         02-SEP-2018 01:23  25:23
```